# Invalid hook call when passing down Stripe promise to Elements provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

Would like to integrate Stripe API in my Django/React project to enable users to pay a monthly subscription. Getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
The above error occurred in the <Elements> component:
```

This is what I have in my app.js

I pass down the stripe promise with my publishable key:

```
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';
...
  const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test***');
...    
                <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                    <AppRoute exact path="/payments" component={CheckoutForm} />
                </Elements>
```

and in my CheckoutForm:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
//import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';
//import ApiService from "../../api";

const CheckoutForm = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    ...
    return (
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } className='stripe-form'>
            <div className='form-row'>
                <label htmlFor='email'>Email Address</label>
                <input className='form-input' id='email' name='name' type='email' placeholder='enter email' required value={ email } onChange={(event)=> { setEmail(event.target.value)}} />
            </div>
            <div className='form-row'>
                <label for='card-element'>Credit or debut card</label>
                <CardElement id='card-element' onChange={handleChange}/>
                <div className='card-errors' role='alert'>{ error }</div>
            </div>
            <button type='submit' className='submit-btn'>
                Submit Payment
            </button>
        </form>
    );
```

**UPDATE**
Here's a complete breakdown of my app.js:

```
...
import CheckoutForm from './components/payments/CheckoutForm';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';

const App = () => {
  ...
  const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test');
  ...
  return (
    <ScrollReveal
      ref={childRef}
      children={() => (
        <Switch>
            <AuthProvider>
                <Header/>
                <AppRoute exact path="/" component={Home} layout={LayoutDefault} />
                <AppRoute exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                <AppRoute exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                <AppRoute exact path="/code_editor" component={CodeEditor} />
                <AppRoute exact path="/timer" component={Timer} />
                <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                    <AppRoute exact path="/payments" component={CheckoutForm} />
                </Elements>
                <RoomContextProvider useGlobalState={useGlobalState}>
                    <AppRoute exact path="/rooms" component={WaitingRoom} />
                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
                    <AppRoute exact path="/rooms/:roomId" component={Room} />
                </RoomContextProvider>
            </AuthProvider>
        </Switch>
      )} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share your complete `app.js` jsx? not sure if you're missing anything in the function body but here's an example: 
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider

Comment: Have you tried moving <Elements> inside AppRoute. 
<AppRoute exact path="/payments">
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    <CheckoutComponent />
  </Elements>
</AppRoute>

Comment: Is the `App.js` class component ?

Comment: @hanzo I have shared my complete `app.js`

Comment: @AnthonyC no it's not, I have shared my complete `app.js` jsx

Comment: I'd try to move the `Elements` rendering inside the `CheckoutForm`. It seems the issue raised when the `Elements` is nested inside `ScrollReveal`, `Switch` or `AuthProvider`